# Jasper report one column size is not same throughout the table

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

There is just one entry in my table but for one of the column the content is so much that it exceeds the page, when we cross the table only the column with content is getting borders and others are not of the same size. Please provide me with the solution.[jasper soft issue with table size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRoYI.png)

I tried changing the setting as mentioned in the image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UC8L.png)

this is the table in jasper reports: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdJvt.png)